# jquery.load - "streaming in" target page to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two pages - one a UI page (simple button with onClick and a display ). The other page uses a component to perform a traceroute. The response buffer on the traceroute page is set so that as it performs each hop, it writes to the browser. This reasonably approximates what you would see in a command window.

Problem is, the jquery.load function seems to only populate the div once the target page is fully received.

Is there a way to uses jquery to make this call so that it writes to the div as the page is received?

JS:

```
function LoadIt(){
    $("#LoadIt").load('testDATA.php');
}
```

HTML:

```
<br><br>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="LoadIt();return false;" class="buttonM bGreyish"><span class="icon-cancel-2"></span><span>Load It</span></a>
<br><br>
<div name="LoadIt" id="LoadIt" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: You didn't post details on this "traceroute" component.  It really depends on how the data comes out of this component.  If the data doesn't stream from the component, then nothing you do will matter.

Comment: The data does indeed stream out of the component. If you visit testDATA.php directly it renders line by line, all ~15 hops, as it loads until it's done.